# Is subprocess + service network-manager a good way for disabling network?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create a context class for disabling & re-enabling network activity on my Linux machine:

```
   class NoNetWorkContext:
       """Context class for disabling and re-enabling network."""
       def __enter__(self, *a, **kw):
           subprocess.run('sudo service network-manager stop', shell=True)
       def __exit__(self, *a, **kw):
           subprocess.run('sudo service network-manager restart', shell=True)
```

and then use it with:

```
with NoNetWorkContext():
    # ...
```

My problems are these:

1. Requires sudo (can be solved by adding me to sudoers list, but
   I'm reluctant to do that)
2. Using `subprocess` (native is better)

Is there a better solution?